# How to get open orders with websocket python-binance?

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I want to get the status of my orders instantly. I reviewed the documents below, but I could not see how to get my open orders with websocket.

https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams

I can get my open orders as seen on this link, but I want to do it with websocket.

orders = client.get_open_orders(symbol='BNBBTC')

https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#id6

Comment: any luck with that ?

Comment: i'm interested as well

Answer (score 0):

It is not a substitute for websocket but I fixed the problem with setInterval.

Backend side app.py

```
@app.route('/allOrders')
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def allOrders():
    openOrders = getAllOrders("LITBUSD")
    return jsonify(openOrders) 

def getAllOrders(symbol):
    try:
        openOrders =  client.get_all_orders(symbol=symbol)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        print("timeout")
        pass 
    return openOrders
```

js side chart.js

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/allOrders')
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)       
    })
 }, 3000);
```

I add the reference in index.html like this.

```
 <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='chart.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Why not suitable?
 https://docs.binance.org/api-reference/dex-api/ws-streams.html

Comment: @Oleg I explained here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65973588/get-orders-with-erc20-address)

Answer (score 0):

[Install Unicorn Binance Websocket API](https://www.lucit.tech/unicorn-binance-websocket-api.html#installation-and-upgrade):

```
pip install unicorn-binance-websocket-api
```

A full example how to query all open orders via Binance Websocket API:

```
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api.manager import BinanceWebSocketApiManager
import asyncio
import logging
import os

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""


async def binance_api_stream(ubwa):
    def handle_socket_message(data):
        print(f"received data:\r\n{data}\r\n")

    ubwa.create_stream(api=True, api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret,
                       process_stream_data=handle_socket_message)
    ubwa.api.get_open_orders(symbol="BNBBTC")
    ubwa.stop_manager_with_all_streams()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger("unicorn_binance_websocket_api")
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        filename=os.path.basename(__file__) + '.log',
                        format="{asctime} [{levelname:8}] {process} {thread} {module}: {message}",
                        style="{")

    ubwa = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange='binance.com')

    try:
        asyncio.run(binance_api_stream(ubwa))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\r\nGracefully stopping the websocket manager...")
        ubwa.stop_manager_with_all_streams()
```

Further information: https://medium.lucit.tech/create-and-cancel-orders-via-websocket-on-binance-7f828831404